# pg_fetch_array error

Tags: php, html, postgresql

This is my current PHP code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from comments where post_id_fk=$post_id';

$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();

while($row = pg_fetch_array($users, 0, PGSQL_ASSOC))
```

For some reason, I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: pg_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/se212004/public_html/content.html on line 39`

The line number refers to the line with the `while` loop. I have tried to fix it several times, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: You have an error in your query. Use `pg_result_error()` to see what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PDO for preparing and executing the statement, and I believe you should also use it for fetching the results. So, basically, you would have to do something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from comments where post_id_fk=$post_id';

$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();

$results = $users->fetchAll();
```

Or you could do:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from comments where post_id_fk=$post_id';

$users = $db->prepare($sql);
$users->execute();

while ($row = $users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      // do something with each row
}
```